# Emissary Ingress and OAuth2 Authentication

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak, ambassador

I have an emissary ingress gateway and I want to authenticate requests with my keycloak server. I see that the integration is available with Edge Stask but, there is an alternative solution ready to use to solve the auth problem? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Emissary ingress has a feature called authservice. This allows you to create the authservice kind and point it to a backend service to handle authentication.

When using keycloak you can use openIDConnect from your authservice backend to  authenticate users to keycloak.

https://www.getambassador.io/docs/emissary/latest/topics/running/services/auth-service/